# How can I know that iMessage is active?

Tags: iphone, messages

If I see such keyboard (please, take a look on the image below), am I right with that: iMessage is active?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upward pointing arrow in green circle indicates that the message will be send as SMS and not as an iMessage. The name/contact of recipient must be green too.

For iMessage the name/contact would be blue.

- Contact shown in blue, registered in iMessage:

[image]

- Contact shown in green, not-registered in iMessage, will be sent an SMS:

[image]

Comment: How does the phone know if it's possible to send an iMessage? Should I save contact phone with "iPhone" mark, but not as default "phone number" or "mobile number"?

Comment: The phone "knows" that the recipient contact is registered in iMessage by contacting Apple's servers. You don't need to do anything or tag it with a special string such as "iPhone". A contact can be registered into iMessage with their email (Apple ID) or phone number (if they have an iPhone). The recipient need not necessarily have an iPhone to receive an iMessage. If they use a Mac, iPod touch or iPad, you can send the iMessage to their email address.